# Return value starting with alphabets

Tags: sql, oracle8i

How to find out values starting with alphabets.

E.g.

I have data

```
prodCode

12FDBC
34IO
ZklM
hOP
12-b.9
```

From the above I would like to have `ZklM` and `hOP` returned. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Why `s.kl` is eliminated in result it starts with alphabet

Comment: @NoDisplayName That was a typo, removed. Thanks

Comment: And which language is it? (Is it the letters A-Z, plus lower case? Or something else?)

Comment: @jarlh Yes, A-Z or a-z

Comment: Does Oracle support ASCII_CODE function, or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is upgrade if at all possible. I can't even find the date that extended support ended for 8i; for 9i it was 2007-07-31, almost 8 years ago.

Failing that, you're simply going to have to enumerate all the characters you want to accept; either something like this, which is overly long:

```
select *
  from ...
 where lower(substr(prod_code, 1, 1)) in ('a', 'b', ..., 'z')
```

Or this, which is less obvious but smaller:

```
select *
  from ...
 where trim(translate(lower(substr(prod_code, 1, 1))
                      , 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ' ')) is null
```

Alternatively, you could create a table with the characters you want to accept and join:

```
select *
  from ... a
     , alphabet b
 where substr(a.prod_code, 1, 1) = b.character
```

Lastly, you could use the `ASCII()` function, which I'm fairly sure existed in 8i

```
select *
  from ...
 where ascii(lower(substr(a.prod_code, 1, 1))) between 97 and 122
```

I explicitly lower case in most of these situations to make life easier; if you want this indexed you're going to have a functional index anyway and an additional `LOWER()` isn't going to make much difference.

Comment: Thanks Ben, ASCII is most efficient. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with oracle, but something like: `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(prodCode, '[aZ].*')`

UPDATED:
It is ugly, it is for MS SQL Server but it might help (I do not know Oracle syntax, the only thing I know that you need to add FROM dual when you select from dummy table):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #test t
WHERE substr(a, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'Z'
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    a VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('12FDBC');
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('34IO');
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('ZklM');
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('hOP');
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('12-b.9');

    SELECT * FROM #test t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM (
SELECT '1' a 
UNION ALL SELECT '2' 
UNION ALL SELECT '3' 
UNION ALL SELECT '4' 
UNION ALL SELECT '5' 
UNION ALL SELECT '6' 
UNION ALL SELECT '7' 
UNION ALL SELECT '8' 
UNION ALL SELECT '9' 
UNION ALL SELECT '0' ) a
    WHERE t.a LIKE a.a + '%'
    )
```

Comment: Regular expressions where added in 10g; this is 2 major versions before that and so will not work. Plus the regular expression itself is incorrect...

Comment: In is very slow operator, and when you specify so many arguments I believe that it is supposed to be slower

Comment: `IN` is not a "slow" operator @sidux. selecting many values from an index makes your query less selective, which may change the explain plan. IN is fine.... the way you use it might not be.